# How to get a table to overlap an image?

Tags: html, css, image, html-table, overlap

Here is a small snippet of my HTML:

```
<img src="http://hss.fullerton.edu/philosophy/Red%20Square.gif" id="test1" />
<table id="test2">
    <tr><td>Test</td></tr>
</table>
```

I have an image of a red square and I want the table to overlap the bottom of it. Here is the CSS:

```
#test1 {
    width: 42px;
    height: 42px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: -15px;
}

#test2 {
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: pink;
    width: 80px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

It isn't working, however:

[image]

As you can see, the image is still on top of the `table` - not what I want. Notice in my CSS that I've explicitly set the table's `z-index` to `1` and it still won't overlap the image. What am I doing wrong?

**jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/george_edison/uk7Pz/

Comment: I think z-index only applies to positioned elements. It might work if you give the table `position:relative`, but then again it might not.

Comment: @sdleihssirhc is right. You should make that an answer so you can get credit for it.

Comment: Yep, it works AFAICT: http://jsfiddle.net/uk7Pz/1/

Comment: I'd make it an answer, but I don't know if it would work in IE6 (you might need to `zoom:1` or something... who knows), and I don't have access to it right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try positioning each element. Add `position:relative` to each element, as demonstrated here: http://jsfiddle.net/8nGKk/1/

Comment: Really? You took @sdleihssirhc's comment-answer and are trying to receive credit for it? ...

Comment: @Blender Not completely, he actually included a JSFiddle sample that proves that it actually works.

Comment: @Blender not at all. I just read the question and posted my answer. I've encountered this before and already knew the answer. I didn't mean to steal any @sdleihssirhc's work.

Comment: @Blender i couldn't decide whether to put a sarcastic or serious response here. :)

Comment: @Blender: It's licensed under CC-wiki like the rest of the site :)

Comment: Lies! It's a commercial licence, costing $19.99 per year of use.